# Binding to primitive value on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-databinding

I am trying to bind to a boolean variable on my controller's scope to indicate whether or not a loading animation should be displayed.  However, the following code does not work.  The function inside `$timeout` runs, but the view is not updated.

When I inspect the scope using the chrome angular extension, I see that `ctrl.loading` is `true`.

Is this because of booleans being value types in javascript, as opposed to reference types?

My guess is that the view is literally binding to `true`, and not to the location of a boolean value which would change.

How do I get the view to bind to the variable, and not to the value, the variable has  initially?

controller:

```
function TestController($scope,$timeout){
    "use strict";

    var loading=true;

    $timeout(function(){
        loading=false;
    }, 1000);

    return {
        loading:loading
    }

}
```

template:

```
<div>
    <h1 ng-show="ctrl.loading">Loading</h1>
    <h1 ng-hide="ctrl.loading">Not Loading</h1>
</div>
```

The abovecode is just an example, really I would set the value after a get request wqas returned.

```
$http.get().then(function() {
    loading=false;
}, function() {
    loading=false;
})
```

but the effect is the same.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$scope.ctrl.loading = false` instead of `loading = false` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding the `loading` variable wrongly. You either need to register that variable `loading` to the `$scope` or to the `this` variable. See the below working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("TestController", TestController);

function TestController($scope, $timeout) {
  "use strict";
  var vm = this;

  vm.loading = true;

  $timeout(function() {
    vm.loading = false;
  }, 2000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  <h1 ng-show="ctrl.loading">Loading</h1>
  <h1 ng-hide="ctrl.loading">Not Loading</h1>
</div>
```

<strike>Also, the return block in the controller is of no use.</strike>

**Edit**

Now, I understand your question. This is the first time I saw this feature of returning from the controller. After half an hour of researching, I found out that you can't expect a primitive type to be passed by reference in Javascript. You need to use some object.

See the scope inheritance problem to get a gist: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

To fix this, you can alter your code like below:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("TestController", TestController);

function TestController($scope, $timeout) {
  "use strict";
  var myData = {};

  myData.loading = true;

  $timeout(function() {
    myData.loading = false;
  }, 2000);

  return {
    myData: myData
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  <h1 ng-show="ctrl.myData.loading">Loading</h1>
  <h1 ng-hide="ctrl.myData.loading">Not Loading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: see my fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/40k8j2L6/).  I can bind to data on the controller that way, and that is what the return statement in the controller is for.

Comment: Oh do you want me to look at the `return` thing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  I'm just saying that the return statement has a use and that in my code if I changed the initial value of loading to true, it would show Not Loading, instead of loading.  the initial binding works, just not the updates.